# Java+Redis vs plain Java efficiency for data intensive applications?

Tags: java, redis, data-mining

Does it help to use Redis with Java to develop data intensive applications (e.g. data-mining) in Java?

Does it work faster or consume less memory comparing to plain Java for similar operation on high volume of data?

Edit: My question is mostly about running on single machine. For example for working with a large number of list/set/maps and query and sort them.

Comment: That depends a lot on what you're trying to do. Is it a single server app? Can you place all this information in memory? Will you run this in a single machine or in many of them?

Comment: @Maurício Currently on single machine, but may scale out in future. Each time I load a large chunk of data in memory to process and then I will save back changes to a small subset of them. Can I improve Java memory/cpu usage efficiency by using Redis with Java on single machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis will definitely not be faster that native Java on a single machine.  It would allow you to distribute processing, but if the chunks of data really are large, they're not likely to fit into memory anyway.  Without knowing more about what you're doing, I would suggest storing the data on disk.  When you get multiple machines, you can network mount the partition and share the data that way.  Alternatively, Hadoop with MapReduce sounds like the right sort of thing for what you're doing.